# Image files uploaded by cPanel File Manager (or Eclipse Import) not displayed by Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I am trying to display an image that I manually uploaded using the cPanel File Manager (or Eclipse Import), using the following in a View:

```
<img src="/app/public/images/logos/DoesNotShow.jpg">
```

and it does NOT show up.  When I take another jpg that already existed:

```
<img src="/app/public/images/logos/DoesShow.jpg">
```

it displays perfectly.  If I download DoesShow.jpg from the cPanel File Manager, rename it WillThisShow.jpg, and then upload (using cPanel File Manger) WillThisShow.jpg to the same folder, and put the following in the view:

```
<img src="/app/public/images/logos/WillThisShow.jpg">
```

it also does NOT display.

I inspected the non-uploaded and the uploaded, and the full correct path was shown for both.

Any ideas?

Comment: check permissions

Comment: Maybe the image is being uploaded as ASCII/Text rather than binary? Browse to the image directly and see what your browser thinks.. eg; http://yourserver/image_dir/WillThisShow.jpg    If your browser reports "can't display image" or something similar, then this is the likely cause. Suggest using an actual FTP client, like Filezilla, or my fave WinSCP

Comment: Check the log (cPanel > Error Log) in the cPanel account for that website right after accessing the website itself. What does that log tell you?

Comment: I am able to view the uploaded image if I just put the url in the address line.  I will check the permissions. Where is the error log in cPanel? Is it just "Errors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have sent your base url `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/'` end it with `/` so you dont have to use it on view. Also make sure you images are outside of the application

```
application

app

app > public

system

index.php
```

config/autoload the url helper.

Then on the image

`<img src="<?php echo base_url('app/public/images/logos/WillThisShow.jpg');?>"`

Comment: The existing image that is displayed, and the uploaded image that is not, both have the same exact path (with the exception of the actual file name), so I don't think that's the problem.  The image path is actually on the production website, while I am testing from the dev website.

Comment: This has been resolved. I had to include the entire path for the uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this If your baseUrl not ending with `/` eg: `http://demo.com` then

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/app/public/images/logos/DoesNotShow.jpg">
```

OR

Change the permission to `0644`